# Generating a Latin Square

Tags: python, python-3.x

I created an algorithm for generating Latin Square. The algorithm uses the first n permutations (Not n!) orderings of a distinct row of numbers. This is then assigned to a 2d list.

```
import itertools

def latin_square(rows, numbers):
    assert rows is not None, "row is required to not be None"
    assert rows >= 0, "row is required to be zero or more, including zero"
    assert numbers is not None, "numbers is required to not be None"
    
    square = [[numbers[0] for row in range(rows)] for col in range(rows)]
    line = [] 
    for row, line in enumerate(itertools.permutations(numbers, rows)):
        if row == rows:
            break
        for col in range(len(line)):
            square[row][col] = line[col]
    return square 

def test_latin_square():
    assert latin_square(1, [1]) == [[1]]
    assert latin_square(2, [0, 1]) == [[0, 1], [1, 0]]
    assert latin_square(2, [-1, -2]) == [[-1, -2], [-2, -1]]
    assert latin_square(3, [3, 2, 1]) == [[3, 2, 1], [3, 1, 2], [2, 3, 1]]

test_latin_square()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Functionality**

Your code is incorrect, as you can see in your fourth test case:

```
latin_square(3, [3, 2, 1]) == [[3, 2, 1],
                               [3, 1, 2],
                               [2, 3, 1]]
```

This is not a latin square, since there are two 3s in the first column and two 1s in the third column. This seems like you wrote the code first and then copied its output to the test cases. It should obviously be the other way round.

The most straight-forward approach would probably be simply rotating the list of `numbers` by one in either direction to get each next row. You should of course make sure to only use distinct numbers from the provided input list `numbers`.

---

**Other suggestions**

These suggestions will improve the existing implementation, but will **not** fix the incorrect functionality.

---

`assert` statements should only be used for testing, as they will be ignored in optimized mode. More about optimized mode [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5142453/9173379). Rather you should check these conditions with an `if`-statement and raise meaningful errors (instead of `AssertionErrors`). `ValueError` or `TypeError` should be the most fitting here (but you could implement your own custom exceptions). One example:

```
if len(set(numbers)) < rows:
    raise ValueError(f"Number of distinct numbers must be greater than or equal to {rows=}")
```

You also don't need to explicitly check for `rows is None` and `numbers is None`, as `None` values will lead to a `TypeError` anyway. Manually checking and providing a meaningful message to the user usually doesn't hurt though.

---

`square = [[numbers[0] for _ in range(rows)] for _ in range(rows)]`

It's a well-known convention to name variables you don't use `_`. That immediately makes it clear to the reader that it's not used and removes unnecessary information.

---

You're doing too much manual work:

1. You don't need to fill `square` with values only to replace them later
2. You don't need to initialize `line` at all
3. You shouldn't (most likely ever) do this:

```
for col in range(len(line)):
    square[row][col] = line[col]
```

All this snippet does is set the value of `square[row]` to `list(line)`:

```
square = []

for row, line in enumerate(itertools.permutations(numbers, rows)):
    if row == rows:
        break

    square.append(list(line))
```

Comment: Could I replace the code with just sifting without generating permutations?

Comment: I presume you mean shifting. Shifting will of course produce certain permutations, but you don't need `itertools.permutations` for it. Simply take `rows` number of distinct numbers for the first row, then keep shifting them (left or right) by one to get the subsequent row. You're very welcome to come back here for further feedback once you've implemented that.