# Generating a Latin Square (Modified Algorithm)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Sifting is used to create a Latin Square of distinct symbols. The sifting is implemented by swaps on an array.  The symbols might be strings or integer, but they are required to be distinct. Notably, this requires deep copy so that the whole Latin Square is not sifted by the same 1.

```
import copy 

def make_latin_square(symbols):
   if symbols is None:
       raise ValueError("symbols is required to not be None")
   square = [] 
   for row in range(len(symbols)):
       symbols[0], symbols[row] = symbols[row], symbols[0]
       square.append(copy.deepcopy(symbols)) 
   return square 
   
def test_make_latin_square():
   assert make_latin_square([0]) == [[0]]
   assert make_latin_square([0, 1, 2]) == [[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 1]]
   assert make_latin_square([-1, -2, -3]) == [[-1, -2, -3], [-2, -1, -3], [-3, -1, -2]]
   

test_make_latin_square()
```

Comment: This is not a latin square.  `[[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [2, 0, 1]]` has `2` in the 3rd column twice,  and `0` in the second column twice.  It looks like your test case was created with the output of your function, not a real test case.  Which is the same issue as your original [post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/262630/100620) had.

Comment: I recommend implementing a function `is_latin_square(square)`, that checks if a square meets all the criteria for a latin square. Once you have that working correctly you won't have to hardcode test case outcomes, which is *obviously* rather error-prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug is that a swap between two elements will not result in a Latin square. Instead, (row + col) % (rows * cols) generates a unique number for each element of the Latin square.